# G_LLL_XD function in NTL library faulty

Tags: ntl

I am trying to use the `G_LLL_XD` function on the NTL library. Whenever I use the function in this format:

```
G_LLL_XD(B, delta); ,
```

the program works.
Though, when I want to change the default deep or prune variables and write the function in one of these ways:

```
G_LLL_XD(B, delta, deep, check, verbose);

G_LLL_XD(B, delta, prune, check, verbose);
```

during runtime, I get this error:

```
R610
- abort() has been called
```

and in the command prompt it says:

```
"sorry...deep insertions not implemented"
```

I find this very weird since whenever I use prune as a variable, I get this crash error, which I shouldn't because the function shouldn't be looking for deep insertion but prune, and when I do use deep as a variable and have implemented deep, I still get an error.

Can anybody help me understand what the problem is or how I can fix this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont found a argument `prune` for LLL function in NTL. But there is one for BKZ. Since the are both accept positive intergers, its only a naming confusion.

From the [documentation](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/LLL.txt):

> NOTE: use of "deep" is obsolete, and has been "deprecated".   It is
>   recommended to use BKZ_FP to achieve higher-quality reductions.
>   Moreover, the Givens versions do not support "deep", and setting
>   deep != 0 will raise an error in this case.

So you can not use `G_LLL_XD` with `deep != 0` but `LLL_XD` should work (but it is deprecated).
But as mentioned, you should consider using `BKZ_XD` instead of `LLL_XD`.
A BKZ basis of a lattice is also LLL reduced, so there should be no problem. BKZ is slower than LLL but you can choose a small Blocksize, maybe 10 or 20 but also 2 or 4 will work, to speed the reduction up.